# PHP and SQL display rows with same value

Tags: php

I've got two tables in SQL like that http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f1fb/2

The query gets all the required information. The problem is that I want to display the information like this (desired final result):
[image]

Some of the PHP Code:(modification on the Query is okey if there is a problem with it)

```
try{
    $db=new readPDO('username');
    $sql="
        SELECT test.SAME, test.Nationality, test.Name, test2.Job
        FROM test
        LEFT JOIN test2
        ON test.noID=test2.noID; 
    ";
    $statement=$db->prepare($sql);
    $statement->execute();
    if($statement->rowCount())
    {

        print"
            <table width='280' border='1'>
            ";
        while ($selector = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            print"<tr><td>$selector[SAME]</td></tr>";
        print"
            </table>
            ";

    }   
    else
        print"Error";
} catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Current result
[image]

Comment: And what happens when you execute the code?

Comment: Just the first row of the image.

Comment: Add your actual result to the code so we can see that.

Comment: is the first column of the first row supposed to be 555555555 ? if not why the last 444, and how are you deciding why it goes there?

Comment: No sorry it supposed to be 555

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a counter to your code to combine the output. For best results, I recommend you first add `order by` to your query.

```
SELECT test.SAME, test.Nationality, test.Name, test2.Job
FROM test
LEFT JOIN test2
ON test.noID=test2.noID
order by test.SAME asc
;
```

Then in the PHP while loop use a counter to calculate the `rowspan` to be applied.

```
$rowspanCounter = 1; 
$_same = '';
while ($selector = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

   if($_same == $selector[SAME]){
   $rowspanCounter++;
   }
   else{
    $_same = $selector[SAME];
    $table_string .= "<tr><td rowspan=".$rowspan.">$selector[SAME]</td>";
    $rowspanCounter = 1;
      }
....//rest of the rows here.


 print"</tr>";
    }
    //outside the while loop
    print "</table>";
```

Comment: I am getting error on _same .
Notice: Undefined variable: _same

Comment: Fixed an error now. You'd have initialize the $_same variable before the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

you looking for this?

```
  SELECT test.SAME , test.Nationality, test.Name, coalesce(test2.Job,'')jobb
  FROM test
  LEFT JOIN test2
  ON test.noID=test2.noID
  group by SAME , name
  order by same desc
```

here example how to [merge two rows](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table_span)